# Sent BCC to BTC wallet, read all treads, and still found no answer

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cash, wallet-recovery

I read all the threads but still no way to recover. I sent BCC from changelly to a BTC wallet.

I tried to import my BTC wallet on a BCC imported wallet by inputing BTC private key while importing a BCC wallet, but gives error.
Anyone can help me recover these lost BCC pleaaaaase?

Thanks

Comment: What wallet software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> I sent BCC from changelly to a BTC wallet.

You can not send BCC/BTC to a wallet. You are sending them to an address.

> I tried to import my BTC wallet on a BCC imported wallet

Never ever do things you do not fully understand

> Anyone can help me recover these lost BCC pleaaaaase?

You should install **bitcoin-abc** and synchronize the blockchain **to a different database folder**. Next, you should import the BTC private key to this client.

Comment: Sorry I do not speak such an elaborated langage^^
I am so happy there is hope on this desperate case...!
Well, if I understood well:
1. I install abc (this is straight away easy)
2. I synchronize the blockchain to a different database folder (I did not understand anything in this one)
3. Import the BTC private key (I know what it is) to this client (what is a client?)

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

SO HAPPY TO WRITE HERE AND HELP BY GIVING WHAT WORKED FOR ME!!
I have a bitcoin.com wallet, and this was the answer of the support team that helped me recovering lost BCH

Hi there,

Please ensure that you set up a Bitcoin Cash sub-wallet within your Bitcoin.com wallet if you have not done so already; there is a video tutorial below for your convenience on youtube, after the adress: watch?v=MyQwUJjTcNY

You will then be able to retrieve the BCC sent to your Bitcoin.com BTC wallet using the following tool (note that you must enter your Bitcoin.com BTC wallet 12 word recovery phrase into this tool):
https://blog.bitpay.com/bitcoin-cash-recovery/

Please note that you will need to translate your receiving Bitcoin Cash address (from your Bitcoin.com BCC wallet) to an address beginning with the letter 'C' using the following tool:
https://jdonadio.github.io/address-translator/

In the second tool above, paste your Bitcoin Cash receiving address from your BCC wallet and copy the new address beginning with 'C'. Return to the first tool, and enter the new address beginning with 'C' as your receiving address. Once you complete the transfer your BCC will appear in your Bitcoin.com BCC wallet.

Regards,

ENjoyyyyy